# How to use instancing offsets

Tags: directx, directx-11

Suppose I have a single buffer of instance data for 2 different groups of instances (ie, I want to draw them in separate draw calls because they use different textures).  How do I set up the offsets to accomplish this?  `IASetVertexBuffers` and `DrawIndexedInstanced` both have offset parameters and its not clear to me which ones I need to use.  Also, `DrawIndexedInstanced` isn't exactly clear if the offset value is in bytes or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Offsets

Those offsets works *independently*. You can offset either in [ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or in [ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstanced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) or in both (then they will combine).

- [ID3D11DeviceContext::IASetVertexBuffers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476456%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts offset *in bytes*:

  ```
   bindedData = (uint8_t*)data + sizeof(uint8_t) * offset
  ```
- [ID3D11DeviceContext::DrawIndexedInstanced](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476410%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) accepts all offsets *in elements* (indices, vertices, instances). They are just values added to indices. Vertex and instance offsets works independently. Index offset also offsets vertices and instances (obviously):

  ```
   index = indexBuffer[i] + StartIndexLocation
   indexVert = index + BaseVertexLocation
   indexInst = index + StartInstanceLocation
  ```

I prefer offsetting in draw call:

- no byte (pointer) arithmetic needed -- less chances to make a mistake
- no need to re-bind buffer if you just changing offset -- less visible state changes (and, hopefully, invisible too)

#### Alternative solution

Instead of splitting rendering to two draw calls, you can merge your texture resources and draw all in one draw call:

- both textures binded at same draw call, branching in shader (if/else) depending on integer passed via constant buffer (simplest solution)
- [texture array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff476906%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) (if target hardware supports it)
- texture atlas (will need some coding, but always useful)

Hope it helps!